# expected output and the practical output not matching, please explain the logic behind the code

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, c-strings

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()

    {

    char *str[] = {"Frogs","Do","Not","Die.","They","Croak"};

    printf("%c %c %c",*str[0],*str[1],*str[2]);//expected F D N

    printf("\n%u %u %u",str[0],str[1],str[2]);//expected 1000 1006 1003

   }
```

this output is based on the assumption that froak begins at 1000

the output is as follows

```
F D N

2162395060 2162395057 2162395053
```

how can that be possible, here the address is decreasing for `str[0]` to `str[2]`, printing the address of `str[3]`, `str[4]`, `str[5]`, shows no pattern and rather have abrupt changes in the addresses

Comment: The compiler may place literal strings *anywhere it pleases*. There doesn't even have to be a pattern that the location is increasing only.

Comment: On a slightly related note, to use [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to print pointers, use the format specifier `"%p"` to print `void *` pointers (and you really should cast the pointers). The `"%u"` format expects `unsigned int` arguments, and pointers aren't `unsigned int` (and may not even be the same size).

Comment: Does it really matter, or it is just for curiosity?

Comment: On a slightly unrelated note, what reasoning could you have to expect `1000 1006 1003` as the addresses? There are lots of things wrong with those three numbers.

Comment: @usr2564301 I chose them just randomnly, but yet what actually are the problems with these three numbers

Comment: @Cid it was only for curiosity because right now I am learning pointers in c

Comment: @rishabhjain okay. As stated Programmer dude, you can't explain this behaviour that can vary. Consider this is magical

Comment: Rishabhjain, it does make you wonder if the authors of the compiler chose to allocate the memory for the string constants in a top-down fashion, similar to the way that stacks allocate memory.  As @Cid has stated, when we try to discern the behavior of a "black box", we must stand back in awe and enjoy the "magic", rather than try to understand it unless the answer is needed to solve our problems :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing the addresses of three string constants.  The compiler is under no obligation to organize the string constants in any predictable fashion.

The compiler is required to provide an array of pointers.  The array can be accessed sequentially to obtain addresses of the string constants, but the string constants may be stored in any location which the compiler deems efficient or useful.

I ran the same code on mac OS using AppleClang 10.0.0.10001044 and got the following output:

```
F D N
104431486 104431492 104431495
```

As you can see, the pointers are sequential using AppleClang.

However, that is irrelevant.  Nothing in your code should depend on how the compiler chooses to allocate memory for the string constants.